# Adding ATL support to existing mfc application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, atl

I want to implement [MFC Docking Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/MFCDockingFramework.aspx)
in my existing mfc application
I have taken same trial, but it gives me assertion like

before execution of my project.

In output window a text appears like:

"Performing registration"

and after that appeared below assertion

File: c:\program files\microsoft visual studio.net 2003\vc7\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h
Line: 2619
Expression: _pAtlModule == 0

Answer (score 5):

For an existing MFC application, you can go to menu `Project`, `Add Class`, and under `ATL` you have an option `Add ATL Support To MFC`. This should add ATL initialization and the module will no longer be `NULL`.

[image]