# stack in AtlAdvise trying to create a connection between OPC server and the client (callback object)

Tags: com, atl

Create Instance of Callback Object using an ATL template

```
CComObject<COPCDataCallback>::CreateInstance(&pCOPCDataCallback);
pCbUnk = pCOPCDataCallback->GetUnknown();
```

it stacked at

```
HRESULT hRes = AtlAdvise(m_IOPCGroupStateMgt,            // [in] IUnknown Interface of the Connection Point
    pCbUnk,              // [in] IUnknown Interface of the Callback object
    IID_IOPCDataCallback,// [in] Connection Point ID: The OPC Data Callback 
    m_dwAdvise           // [out] Cookie that that uniquely identifies the connection
    );
```

unhandled exception at XXXX ntdll.dll
before that I added ATL support to the MFC project

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8046824/4270170

any ideas to solve this issue?
thanks.

Comment: For any unhandled exception you are interested in getting call stack to specify the location of exception. The problem is likely to be in `COPCDataCallback` implementation which you don't show. One of the typical things to check is whether code execution unexpectedly reaches `~COPCDataCallback` because it might so happen you incorrectly do COM references.

Comment: dear Roman R.，I have checked the code executes the constructor and then return to the next code of AtlAdvise, it didn't reach the destructor. so the CComObject object is still in the stack. I think the issue is related to the       ATL thing at which i am a novice.Do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be my fault that the type of the fourth param of AtlAdvise is DWORD，but there is something wrong with this param I set.And now  everything goes well.Thank you all.